Why do I get CS8603 (Possible null reference return) here even though I have an IsNullOrEmpty check?
I am encountering a strange situation here where my code that is guarded by IsNullOrEmpty check still emits CS8603:
    public static string GetIpAddress(this HttpContext ctx)
    {
        // Try Cloudflare Header
        if (ctx.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("CF-Connecting-IP", out var ip) 
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
        {
            return ip; // Warning here
        }

        // Return from the connection
        return ctx.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString() ?? "0.0.0.0";
    }


At first I thought it's an IDE issue but dotnet build returns the same warning.
I even made sure the framework's definition is correct and it is (using VS' Source Link):
        public static bool IsNullOrEmpty([NotNullWhen(false)] string? value)
        {
            return value == null || value.Length == 0;
        }

What is going on here? Why is CS8603 happening here?

Hmm after looking at my screenshot again, my guess would be because ip is StringValues instead of string and the implicit conversion didn't survive the null check (should it?). I thought ip were string when I wrote this question.

It seems the HeaderDictionary.TryGetValue does not have [NotNullWhen(true)] on the out param. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3f1acb59718cadf111a0a796681e3d3509bb3381/src/Http/Http/src/HeaderDictionary.cs#L319C9-L324C50

@Magnus I don't think NotNullWhen(true) would work there even. The type StringValues cannot be null, and when I use return ip, an implicit conversion is performed and it's not actually ip being returned, it's something like ip.ToString() (i.e. a different string instance).

Looking at the source, the implicit operator calls the GetStringValue method, which can return null. The compiler doesn't know that multiple calls will return the same value, which is why the IsNullOrEmpty check doesn't help.

StringValues means there can be more than 1 value, especially if the header is custom. Which one would you want? Assuming there's no CF-Connecting-IP: header you could use list pattern matching, eg && ip is [ip1,_] to get and use the first IP. Or a property pattern, ip is {Count > 0}

@PanagiotisKanavos man I can't believe that syntax actually works! Learn new 'magic' every day. (it becomes && ip is [var ip1, _] && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip1))

@LukeVo you could use {} ip1 to avoid the null, or even {Length>1} ip1 but that's starting to get ugly. I'm saying could because I can't verify this just now

Some time ago, since it's IEnumerable, I'd suggest to use pattern matching ip.FirstOrDefault() is string ip1, but collection decomposition or what is ip is [string ip1, _] (note string) is more modern.

That happens because the compiler is confused about the actual value of this string. To "fix" this, you need to force its interpretation. Try the code below:
return ip.ToString();
